# Which Imam of Shia has more hadiths?

Tags: hadith, shiism, ali, shia-imam, imam-sadiq

As it is clear, there are many narrations from Shia Imams. (As well as the traditions of Prophet Muhammad (SAWW). I couldn’t exactly figure out which Imam has the most hadiths? Or in other word, most of Shia hadiths are from who? (Except the apostle of Allah (SAWW) who has the most narrated hadiths)

*(**Note:** Although it is said that Imam Ali, Imam Sadiq and Imam Baqer (peace be upon them) have the most ahadith, but I am looking for the answer by authentic reference)*

Answer (score 1):

According to the chief of the “Hawza-Elmia-Qom Mahdaviat expert center”, it is declared that:

**Imam Sadiq (الامام جعفرالصادق علیه السلام)  has the most traditions (hadiths) (which have been quoted from him...) as the sixth Imam of Shiite.**

In other word, the most hadiths have narrated from him in compare with other Shia Imams. In addition to Imam Jafar-Al-Sadiq (a.s.), there are many hadiths which were narrated from Imam Ali (علیه السلام) and Imam Mohammad-al-Baqir (Baqer) (علیه السلام) as well, who can be deemed as the other Imams who have more hadiths in compare with other Shi'i Imams.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.farsnews.com](http://www.farsnews.com/newstext.php?nn=13931019000063)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, Imam Jaafar al-Sadiq (slightly confusingly called 'Abu Abdullah' like Imam Hussein) has the most.

Comment: Please consider taking your time to elaborate a good answer (read [answer]), as is this looks more likely to be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Imam Sadiq (PBUH) and Imam Baqir (PBUH) seem to be the most narrated Hadith Imams whose Hadithes are available* 
As you might know, several papers of Ahadith were narrated by Imam Hadi (PBUH) that got burnt not a long time later.
Or many Ahadith of Imam Ali (PBUH) had been censored by the government of that time.